# Search component Flyout fields not displaying

Tags: content-hub

As a discovery task, I build a small Search page ("New Search") patterned after the Assets page, enabling Asset search functionality bit by bit to understand (and explain) how the Search component functions (adding facets, etc.).   I ran into a snag demoing flyouts (also know as "Previews"). On my new page they display, but they don't have zoom enabled and don't display entity fields. I have not been able to identify why this works for Assets, but not my page.

My flyout with no text fields:
[image: Flyout display of a glass of orange juice without text fields to the right]

Asset page flyout with text fields displayed:
[image: Flyout showing orange tree with fields displayed to right]

My New Search page is defined like this (basic page as is Assets):
[image]

My search component is defined like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can't identify a meaningful difference from the main Assets page that would account for the behavior difference.  I've been able to add fields to the Assets flyout, so I don't believe latency is a factor.

Things I've tried:

- Clearing cache, restarting the sandbox.
- Enabling "Selection", "Enabling Track State" options on the Search component.
- Changing the preview display option.

Content Hub version 3.4.6, sandbox with Fruitful snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that I created New Search as a "Basic" page, rather than an "Detail" page. I recreated it as a Detail page (for M.Asset):

[image]

Next I added a Search component with one field on the Flyout, and the field displayed:
[image]

Comment: Thanks to Anna Bründel for pointing me in the right direction on Slack.

Comment: Although this resolved the issue, it's worth noting that the Assets page is not set with an Entity Definition, so there must be some other way to resolve this issue.